How do I update my record when there is a duplicate value in SQL Server?
I am trying to figure out how to update my record when there is a duplicate value in SQL server.
My data warehouse table has an old record and a new record in it that looks like this:



dw_id
hash_key
hash_diff
week_day
active_ind
expiry_date
updated_date
created_date




699
oaijfoieae
93onjios
SATURDAY
1
12/31/3030
12/31/3030
04/24/2024


699
oaijfoieae
34hrjios
SUNDAY
1
12/31/2030
12/31/3030
04/25/2024



I want it to look like this:



dw_id
hash_key
hash_diff
week_day
active_ind
expiry_date
updated_date
created_date




699
oaijfoieae
93onjios
SATURDAY
0
04/25/2024
04/25/2024
04/24/2024


699
oaijfoieae
34hrjios
SUNDAY
1
12/31/2030
04/25/2024
04/25/2024



I want to update the value where the hash_key is the same for that record but the hash_diff is different for that record. So above, both hash_keys are the same but the hash_diffs are different. I want my query to:
UPDATE DW.dbo.stg_table_name
WHERE hash_key is duplicated for the single record but the hash_difs are different
SET active_ind = 0 WHERE active_ind = 1
AND where expiry_date = 12/31/3030
SET expiry_date = GETDATE()

but then update the new record (SUNDAY) updated_date to the current date as well?
I am not sure if I can do this because I know what I want to do in my mind but my SQL doesn't make sense, outside of not being written in appropriate syntax. Wouldn't both records be updated since both initially have an active_ind of 1 and technically both hash_diff's are different so how would it know which record to update? Maybe I should pick which created_date is more recent? I have it set to the current date so when it gets imported from the source to the data warehouse, it should update the record to the current day...

Try this:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #source;
CREATE TABLE #source (dw_id integer, hash_key nvarchar(50),hash_diff nvarchar(50),week_day nvarchar(50),active_ind bit, expiry_date date, updated_date date, created_date date);
 
INSERT INTO #source
VALUES
(699, 'oaijfoieae','93onjios','SATURDAY',1,   '3030-12-31','3030-12-31', '2024-04-24'),
(699, 'oaijfoieae','34hrjios','SUNDAY', 1,  '2030-12-31', '2030-12-31', '2024-04-25')

-- Get all duplicated hash_keys 
;with cte as (
select hash_key  from #source
group by hash_key
having count(hash_diff)>1
)

-- update rows based on hash_keys
-- rw = 1 is the first one based on created_date= 04/24/2024
update #source set active_ind = case when tbl.rw=1 then 0 else 1 end,
expiry_date = case when tbl.rw=1 then GETDATE() else expiry_date end,
updated_date=GETDATE()

from
(select hash_key, hash_diff, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by hash_key order by created_date) rw  from #source
where hash_key in (select hash_key from cte)
) tbl

where #source.hash_key = tbl.hash_key and #source.hash_diff=tbl.hash_diff

select * from #source

First I got the duplicated rows based on hash_key and then updated the table based on Row_Number.
SQL Fiddle
